# raise floor level and floor over cavity, is there a better solution?

Tags: wood, flooring

We have had two walls removed to open into an extension (340x320cm) and to add french doors to the extension.
We face 2 issues:

- The dining room floor is at a slightly lower level to the kitchen
  either side of the now gone wall.
- The floor does not reach the door
  because of the cavity. (And also its slightly lower level than the door)

My thinking is to lay 22mm chipboard sheets over the dining room floor and screw them into the subfloor boards. Where these reach the door my thinking is have them overhang the cavity as it is only a small gap they should be ok anchored into the existing floor?

Is there a better approach?

Photos:
[image]
[image]

Comment: A better photo of that gap would be great. It's hard to interpret from above, and I'm getting dizzy.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what "chipboard" is, but your plan is ok if you use a structural sheet material (OSB or plywood). The span across the wall void is wide enough that you should find a way to support the sheet at the far side, though, or it's likely to flex a fair bit.

Comment: I've always thought that chipboard was OSB, but I've never been quite sure, and I don't know what they would call particle board...  Good to get clarification.

Comment: Something like https://www.wickes.co.uk/Wickes-P5-T+G-Chipboard-Flooring---22mm-x-600mm-x-2400mm/p/164536. What if join them with a c16 stud on the underside which will sit in the cavity? Hopefully make it a little more rigid?

Comment: Floating lumber underneath won't help unless you attach the lumber. Concrete screws or construction adhesive would probably work.

Comment: Chip board is made from pieces has pieces about 1cm / 0.5"  in length  OSB is made from has pieces about 15cm / 6" in length, but otherwise yeah both are made from wood fragments.

Comment: What's the actual industry term for "chip board"? I'm having trouble finding a reference.